# Add css file conditionally if the page is shopping cart using xml

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, css

I need to add css file to shopping cart page. But it should only added to the that page. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add this xml code in your local.xml it will add css only for cart page

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">

           <reference name="head">

                <action method="addCss">
                    <stylesheet>css/style.css</stylesheet>
                </action>
            </reference>
        </checkout_cart_index>
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento is *`create a unique handler`* whenever ***the  cart page is rendered***.For cart page,the handler is *`checkout_cart_index`*. and the  this handler a use of `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head`  class's `addCss()` function you can add css file.

How to use this at layout files ,you can try   [Qaisar Satti Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/88686/4564)

In each page,***magento is create a handler*** which value is ***same  as front Controller Full Action Name*** (
   `Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName()`).

**Format**:

> ```
> <'Handler_Name' translate="label">
> <reference name="head">
> <action method="addCss">
>     <stylesheet>css/style.css</stylesheet>
> </action>
> </reference>
> </'Handler_Name'>
> ```